# Array Index selection C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a array of length 300 of type int. Most of the element is 0 and I want to get the index of the first element that is greater than 0. How can I achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: Perform linear search. A simple `for` loop.

Comment: How do you think you can achieve this? What did you try yourself to solve the problem, and at what point exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Actually I am confused how to achieve it. I havent implemented it but my idea is like this, using a for-loop and determine the index of 1st element not equal to 0. Infact this will give the index of all the element not equal to zero and I select the element minimum in the list.

Comment: @user1965914: `for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i) { if(array[i] > 0) { /* i is your index */ } }`

Comment: @user1965914: That sounds good for a start - why haven't you implemented it? Is there any specific question about `for` syntax?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `for` loop to go from index 0 to `yourArray.length - 1` and record the index of the first element with a value greater than 0.

```
int firstIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    if (yourArray[i] > 0) {
        firstIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternately, use a method which returns `i` immediately on finding the index, instead of breaking the loop. In this case, return either `-1` (or some other value that can't be a valid index, but -1 is fairly common in the .NET libraries) or an exception, depending on your tastes.

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan. My mistake was i was not placing the break and hence i created a new array for copying the index and determine the min which was just messy. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
array.ToList().FindIndex(value => value > 0)
```

Alternatively, create your own `FindIndex` extension method for generic arrays:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this T[] array, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (predicate(array[index]))
            return index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

which would remove the need for LINQ and `ToList()`:

```
array.FindIndex(value => value > 0)
```

Comment: Just on the off-chance OP has negative numbers in the array, I'd suggest `(value => value > 0)`, since he wants the index of the first element greater than 0. :)

Comment: Calling `ToList()` isn't ugly, it's quite simple. It *may* pose a performance problem. I doubt OP will ever notice it, though.

Then again, writing a FindIndex extension methods for arrays is going to be simple enough.

Comment: @Alan, depends on your definition of ugly. Why write five lines when one will do?

Comment: I agree, @zmbq, there's no need to prematurely optimize. The speed difference will probably not be human-perceivable for one 300-item array. Just for fun I added an extension method to my answer as an alternative.

Comment: @GregHaskins It's sloppy to me. All he needs to do is loop through and find something in an array. To me it feels as if people jump to using LINQ and other C# convenience features without fully understanding how they work, even if the performance impact is insignificant in this case it is still ridiculous to put everything in a new list first. Also, if the asker doesn't understand how to do a simple linear search, why throw in something more complicated such as LINQ and Lambda expressions? I'd suggest the simple for-loop, then the extension method to array if you want to expand on the idea.

Comment: @GregHaskins The extension method is better, but I will still claim that the simple for-loop construct is going to be most easily understood by someone who is apparently new to programming and the language. (Also please understand I'm not trying to imply you do not know how ToList() works, but I'm not sure about the novice that would come across it)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get the index of first element of the array which is greater than 0,

```
var array = new int[5];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 0;
array[2] = 1;
array[3] = 1;
array[4] = 0;

int index = Array.FindIndex(array, x=>x > 0);
```

Or,you can use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method of Array,

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, array.First(x=>x > 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get its value, you can use LINQ:

```
array.Where(x=>x>0).First
```

If you want its index, you can use LINQ but it'll be more complicated than a straight loop - go over all elements and see if one of them is not 0.

Comment: I would use `array.First(x => x > 0);`. No need to traverse the entire collection if you only want the first match.  Anyway, he asked for the index.

Comment: Oh, yeah, simpler. Didn't realize First can get a predicate.

Comment: I thought that it doesn't evaluate the whole list in either case. Running this in linqpad seems to indicate that both cases stop at the first ocurrence. `var array = new [] {0,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,9,10};
array.Where(x => {Console.WriteLine(x); return x > 0;}).First();` Results are 0,0,0,0,0,0,5

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<numbers.Length;i++)
{

  if(numbers[i]>0)
  {
    break;
  }
  count++;
}
```

get the value of variable count at last, that is goint to be index.

Comment: `count` will be off by 1, giving him the index of the first matching element + 1.

Comment: @Tim : sorry, will it be fine now?

Answer (score 0):

```
int result;

foreach (int i in array)
    if (i > 0)
    {
        result = i;
        break;
    }
```

Since you only want the first, you can break as soon as you find it.